# Javascript only validates my first input

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and i'm trying to validate my form, but for some reasons, my code only takes into account the first input.

If I try to insert a 1 char input name, it gives me the correct alert box, but if I insert a 1 char input last name, it doesn't show me the same alert box.

I can't see my mistake...why is it processing only first input? Can anybody help me?

**HTML**

```
<form action="registration" name="registrationForm" method="post" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
    <p> Nome <p>
    <input type="text" class="registrationInput" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required maxlength="45"/>
    <p> Cognome </p>
    <input type="text" class="registrationInput" name="cognome" placeholder="Cognome" required maxlength="45"/>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function formValidation(){

    var name = document.registrationForm.nome;
    var surname = document.registrationForm.cognome;

    if(validateName(name)){
        if(validateSurname(surname)) {
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function validateName(name){
    if(name.value.length <= 3 || name.value.length >=45) {
        window.alert("Il nome non è corretto. Deve essere lungo da un minimo di 4 a un massimo di 45 caratteri");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function validateSurname(surname) {
    if(surname.value.length <= 3 || surname.value.length >=45) {
        window.alert("Il cognome non è corretto. Deve essere lungo da un minimo di 4 a un massimo di 45 caratteri");
        surname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Because it only validates the second box if the first one passes...!? Because you're nesting it in an `if`...!?

Comment: It only validates the first box, dude, even if the second is wrong. Don't be rude and read the question.

Comment: As I said: if the first one is wrong, the second is never validated. Does it validate the second when the first one is correct (it should)?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. But it's not what I asked for. See the correct answers below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if(validateName(name)){
    if(validateSurname(surname)) {
    }
}
```

The error is that if the first function call validateName(name) returns false, the second call will be ignored. Maybe you have to check the inputs separated.

```
if(validateName(name)){

}

if(validateSurname(surname)) {
}
```

**Update after read comments**

Easy as a flag to know what is the input that fails

```
var flag = true;

if(!(validateName(name) && flag)){
    flag = false;
    alert("Input 1 fails");
}


if(!(validateSurname(surname) && flag)){
    flag = false;
    alert("Input 2 fails");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i want that behaviour. If i insert a wrong input in the form, i want to see an alert that shows me the first error i done. In your example, instead, if I set wrong inputs, I have to show different alerts at the same time, one for all my mistakes. It's a little bit stressing :D

Comment: Why not check them separatedly? You only want to display the first error for the validation of the input?

Comment: No, I want to display the first error done when i click to "submit".
Here we have two input form: input1 and input2.
input1: incorrect, input2:correct -->submit--> alert(input1 is incorrect)
input1: correct, input2: incorrect -->submit--> alert(input2 is incorrect)
input1: incorrect, input2: incorrect -->submit--> alert(input1 is incorrect)
Sorry for the bad formatting :-(

Comment: I really like your style! I think that I will use your advice cause it appears better to me. Thanks, I haven't considered the simplicity of a flag. I have a lot to learn ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
if(validateName(name)){
    if(validateSurname(surname))
```

If and only if `validateName` returns `true` does `validateSurname` run. If you always unconditionally want to validate both, you must not nest them conditionally:

```
var valName = validateName(name),
    valSurname = validateName(surname);

return valName && valSurname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try to validate the fields is quite inneficient. I recommend you to try this:

```
    function formValidation(){
        var nome = document.getElementsByName('nome')[0];
        var cognome = document.getElementsByName('cognome')[0];

        if(!validateInput(nome)){
            //input nome validation is false
            alert("Il nome non è corretto. Deve essere lungo da un minimo di 4 a un massimo di 45 caratteri");
            nome.focus();
            return;
        }

        if(!validateInput(cognome)){
            //input cognome validation is false
            alert("Il cognome non è corretto. Deve essere lungo da un minimo di 4 a un massimo di 45 caratteri");
            cognome.focus();
            return;
        }
    }

    function validateInput(input){
        //input parameter MUST be a DOM Element

        var input_name = input.getAttribute("name");

        //Validation of "nome" input
        if(input_name == "nome"){

            //Minimum length is 4 and maximum length is 45
            if(input.value.length > 3 && input.value.length < 46){
                return true; //This will break execution and return true
            }
        }

        //Validation of "cognome" input
        else if(input_name == "cognome"){

            //Minimum length is 4 and maximum length is 45
            if(input.value.length > 3 && input.value.length < 46) {
                return true; //This will break execution and return true
            }

            //This input validation is exactly the same as
            //nome input validation, so you should ommit the
            //code duplication and use the same validation for
            //both fields.
        }

        //Add more field validations if needed...
        //. . .

        //If the input passed as a parameter doesn't pass the validation
        //this function will return false.
        return false;
    }
```

I also highly recommend you to use ***jQuery*** for form validation, as It simplifies it a lot, compare yourself:

```
function formValidation(){

    var passedvalidation = true;

    //Iterate on all registration inputs
    $(".registrationInput").each(function(){
        var input = $(this); //Get the input object
        var input_name = $(input).attr("name"); //Get the input name

        if(input_name == "nome"){
            //Validate "nome" input
            //If validation is false show message, change input color, etc...
            passedvalidation = false;
        }

        else if(input_name == "cognome"){
            //Validate "cognome" input

            //If validation is false show message, change input color, etc...
            passedvalidation = false;
        }
    });

    return passedvalidation;
}

//Call form validation function and that's all
if(formValidation()){
   //send post to process the form
}
```

Comment: I am grateful for your time spent for me, but there is no need to make things complicated. It' only a simple example to understand better the return values of javascript functions. Of course in my code I will improve myself and I will see some jQuery form validation. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

The function formValidation() returns nothing when validation is OK.

Before validateSurname if, you need to return true.

```
...
if(validateName(name)){
    if(validateSurname(surname)) {
        return true;  // <-- YOU NEED TO ADD THIS
    }
}
return false;
...
```

Hope this help you  :)

Comment: Thanks, I was sure to had already try it...but i don't. It works, thanks for your time :-)